# Segue, what happens to UIViewController and self.view on the heap?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue

When viewDidUnload is called on a UIViewController self.view is ultimately destroyed with its allocated memory being returned to the heap, but the parent UIViewController stays on the heap.

When working with storyboards performing a segue results in the destination controller and its associated views being created and initialised, the next time the segue is performed a brand new controller is created.

My question is does anyone know if ultimately the segue returns both the UIViewController and the views to the heap, I would assume it does as everything will get created a fresh the next time the segue is performed?

Comment: side note: `viewDidUnload` is deprecated. It is not called in iOS 6.

Answer (score 1):

I'd build a test app. The result of the test is that after calling viewDidUnload (in the target viewController) an performing the seque again new view- and viewController instances (of the target viewController)been created.

Comment: Thanks Areal, thats certainly an option, I was hoping that someone might know offhand. Its not really a problem, I was just curious about the mechanics behind the scenes. I will do a testbed and check to see if new instances are created. Much appreciated ...